# AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'size' pretrained bert

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, bert-language-model, pre-trained-model

This is the model that I have defined:

```
def build_model():
  input_layer = keras.layers.Input(name="Input", shape=(MAX_LEN), dtype='int64')
  bert = BertForPreTraining.from_pretrained('digitalepidemiologylab/covid-twitter-bert-v2')(input_layer)
  bert = bert[0][:,0,:]
  x = keras.layers.Bidirectional(keras.layers.LSTM(256, name="LSTM", activation='tanh', dropout=0.3), name="Bidirectional_LSTM")(bert)
  x = keras.layers.Dense(64, 'relu')(x)
  output_layer = keras.layers.Dense(1, 'sigmoid', name="Output")(x)

  model = keras.Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=output_layer)

  model.compile(loss=loss,
                optimizer=optimizer)
  return model
```

On running
`model = build_model()`

This is the error I am getting.

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-57-671884cecb64> in <module>()
----> 1 model = build_model()

4 frames
<ipython-input-56-ef0d67347557> in build_model()
      1 def build_model():
      2   input_layer = keras.layers.Input(name="Input", shape=(MAX_LEN), dtype='int64')
----> 3   bert = BertForPreTraining.from_pretrained('digitalepidemiologylab/covid-twitter-bert-v2')(input_layer)
      4   bert = bert[0][:,0,:]
      5   x = keras.layers.Bidirectional(keras.layers.LSTM(256, name="LSTM", activation='tanh', dropout=0.3), name="Bidirectional_LSTM")(bert)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
    720             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    721         else:
--> 722             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    723         for hook in itertools.chain(
    724                 _global_forward_hooks.values(),

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/transformers/modeling_bert.py in forward(self, input_ids, attention_mask, token_type_ids, position_ids, head_mask, inputs_embeds, labels, next_sentence_label, output_attentions, output_hidden_states, return_dict, **kwargs)
    938             output_attentions=output_attentions,
    939             output_hidden_states=output_hidden_states,
--> 940             return_dict=return_dict,
    941         )
    942 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
    720             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    721         else:
--> 722             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    723         for hook in itertools.chain(
    724                 _global_forward_hooks.values(),

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/transformers/modeling_bert.py in forward(self, input_ids, attention_mask, token_type_ids, position_ids, head_mask, inputs_embeds, encoder_hidden_states, encoder_attention_mask, output_attentions, output_hidden_states, return_dict)
    793             raise ValueError("You cannot specify both input_ids and inputs_embeds at the same time")
    794         elif input_ids is not None:
--> 795             input_shape = input_ids.size()
    796         elif inputs_embeds is not None:
    797             input_shape = inputs_embeds.size()[:-1]

AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'size'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is caused because, you have created the Keras or Tensorflow based model. However, `BertForPreTraining` is a pytorch model.
Hence, you have to call the Tensorflow based BERT model as:

```
from transformers import TFBertForPreTraining

###other lines of code###

bert = TFBertForPreTraining.from_pretrained('digitalepidemiologylab/covid-twitter-bert-v2')(input_layer)

###other lines of code###
```